# why the translation api of python version demo api timeout when invoked

Tags: python, api, timeout, translation

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import translate

# Instantiates a client
translate_client = translate.Client()

# The text to translate
text = u'Hello, world!'

# The target language
target = 'ru'

# Translates some text into Russian
translation = translate_client.translate(
    text,
    target_language=target)
print(u'Text: {}'.format(text))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(translation['translatedText']))
```

I use google translation api of python version demo,and find that the method translate_client.translate allways throws timeout excption ,what is wrong with this?[timeout when the method called.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUTT0.png)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled5/translatetest.py", line 15, in 
    print(u'Text: {}'.format(text))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\translate_v2\client.py", line 233, in translate
    method='POST', path='', data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 290, in api_request
    headers=headers, target_object=_target_object)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 183, in _make_request
    return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 212, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 201, in request
    method, url, data=data, headers=request_headers, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

Comment: Hi, can you add the error lines in your question, not an image, but just code text.

Comment: ok,I have added the error details.

Comment: I have tried the  google translation api of  .NET version demo too,there are the same problems. 
My network can access to google home page , I have to use vpn to access google  becuase for some reason in my country